# How do I write an .htaccess file so that it can proxy images outside of the web root on an Apache server?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I want to proxy a bunch of images on my Apache server so that they are not stored in the webroot.
Specifically, I have all my images in the following folder on my Linux server:

```
/var/www/img/
```

However, I want it so that when a user goes to `mydomain.com/img/img1.jpg` (which has the server path `/var/www/html/img/img1.jpg`), it references the following file outside of the webroot:

```
/var/www/img/img1.jpg
```

It seems like this is possible using the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` rules in an `.htaccess` file (source: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html#proxy), but I'm having trouble understanding their syntax and which path goes where, etc.

Given my above situation, could someone please provide some explicit code that I can write into an `.htaccess` file to achieve what I want?

---

**Edit**: I just solved this problem by adding the following one line to my Apache `httpd.conf` file, and then restarting the server:

```
Alias "/img" "/var/www/img"
```

Where the `/img` part refers to the `img` directory in my webroot, and the `/var/www/img` part refers to the Linux filesystem directory I want to point to with the actual files in it.

Comment: When I host images (or anything) outside of the webroot that needs to be accessible to the public, I use a symlink. Is that an option for you? I.e. `ln -s /var/www/img /var/www/html/img`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I'm probably doing it incorrectly, but I typed what you recommended and there were no errors, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It could be a few things, hard to say since I don't know your setup. In general, the idea is to symlink your images folder that is *not* on the webroot to some place that *is* on your webroot. Your site must also be configured to follow symlinks.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and figure out what's going on. Ideally though, I wanted to be able to control the proxying from the Apache level, not the OS level. Still, thank you.

Comment: That's totally fair, I just wanted to give you other options. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to add a symbolic link to your other folder:

```
ln -s /my/target/folder /var/www/html/mynewfolder
```

If you can edit the Apache conf file for the server you need to add the FollowSymLinks directive in the directory block:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/">
   AllowOverride All
   Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

You might also be able to add that to your .htaccess file as `Options +FollowSymLinks` if you can't edit the Apache file

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this with the PassThrough [PT flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt) and mod_rewrite.

You create an alias to the actual path and then use it in the rule.

```
Alias "/img" "/var/www/img/"
RewriteRule "img/(.+)\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$" "/img/$1.$2" [PT]
```

See how that works for you.

Comment: Panama Jack, I'm not sure if you were writing your answer while I was editing my question, but I did exactly what you suggested with the `Alias` directive, and that alone seems to solve my problem. What does `RewriteRule` with the `PT` flag add that `Alias` alone doesn't provide? Thanks.

Comment: Probably nothing now. PT rule would have been more helpful if you didn't have the **same name** as your alias. `img`. For instance if it was `pics` in the URL then the PT rule would solve the issue along with `Alias`. e.g. `RewriteRule "pics/(.+)\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$" "/img/$1.$2" [PT]` See why you would need it then?

Comment: @HartleySan Since this help solve your problem please accept the answer.